# Common NSConnection for various data proccessing from web server in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, nsconnection

How to have common NSConnection for various data processing from web server in iPhone. If possible can I have code for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote some blog posts about NSURLConnection.

[Using NSURLConnection](http://www.conceitedcode.com/2010/06/using-nsurlconnection/)

[Sending POST Data Using NSURLConnection](http://www.conceitedcode.com/2010/06/sending-post-data-using-nsurlconnection/)

Hope This Helped. Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Hi,
I done already NSURLConnection it. but i want to connect to server for   various view controller to retrieve data? whether it is no problem to have no main thread to connect to server?

Comment: What are you trying to retrieve? All the data that the server sends to your application is stored as an instance of NSData. You have to convert the data to what you want. And it could be a problem if it is on the main thread, but it really just depends on how much data you are transferring. It is good practice to have connect to a server on another thread.